# Android Studio Find Friends is not working using firebase realtime database(E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm a cs student and now I have to write an app using firebase and android studio for a project.

I'm so new in this and now I faced a problem. in my FindFriends activity when i run my app and then search for any user it starts to show all the users(Even deleted one) and not the one I searched in the box.

also it says E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout and I couldn't find why?

Here is my FindFriends Activity:

```
{
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private ImageButton SearchButton;
    private EditText SearchInputText;  //searchField

    private RecyclerView SearchResultList;

    private DatabaseReference allUsersDatabaseRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_friends);

        allUsersDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.find_friends_app_bar_layout);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Search For Friends");

        SearchResultList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.search_result_list);
        SearchResultList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        SearchResultList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        SearchButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.search_for_friends_button);
        SearchInputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box_input);

        SearchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String searchBoxInput = SearchInputText.getText().toString();

                SearchForFriends(searchBoxInput);
            }
        });


    }

    private void SearchForFriends(String searchBoxInput)
    {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Searching...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Query searchForFriendsQuery = allUsersDatabaseRef.orderByChild("fullname")
                .startAt(searchBoxInput).endAt(searchBoxInput + "\uf8ff");


        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<FindFriends> option =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<FindFriends>()
                .setQuery(allUsersDatabaseRef, FindFriends.class)
                .build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FindFriends, FindFriendsViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter
                = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FindFriends, FindFriendsViewHolder>(option)
        {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FindFriendsViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull FindFriends model)
            {
                holder.setFullname(model.getFullname());
                holder.setStatus(model.getStatus());
                holder.setProfileimage(getApplicationContext(), model.getProfileimage());

                holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        String  visit_user_id = getRef(position).getKey();

                        Intent profileIntent = new Intent(FindFriendsActivity.this, PersonProfileActivity.class);
                        profileIntent.putExtra("visit_user_id", visit_user_id);
                        startActivity(profileIntent);
                    }
                });
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public FindFriendsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
            {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.all_users_display_layout,parent, false);

                FindFriendsViewHolder viewHolder = new FindFriendsViewHolder(view);

                return viewHolder;
            }
        };

        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
        SearchResultList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    public class FindFriendsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        View mView;

        public FindFriendsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setProfileimage(Context ctx ,String profileimage)
        {
            CircleImageView myImage = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.all_users_profile_image);
            Picasso.get().load(profileimage).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(myImage);
        }

        public void setFullname(String fullname)
        {
            TextView myName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.all_users_full_name);
            myName.setText(fullname);
        }

        public void setStatus(String status)
        {
            TextView myStatus = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.all_users_Status);
            myStatus.setText(status);
        }


    }

}
```

also my FindFriends class:

```
package com.example.pingoo;

public class FindFriends
{
    public String profileimage, fullname, status;

    public FindFriends()
    {

    }

    public FindFriends(String profileimage, String fullname, String status) {
        this.profileimage = profileimage;
        this.fullname = fullname;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getProfileimage() {
        return profileimage;
    }

    public void setProfileimage(String profileimage) {
        this.profileimage = profileimage;
    }

    public String getFullname() {
        return fullname;
    }

    public void setFullname(String fullname) {
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }


}
```

I will appreciate if anyone could help me with this because it's sooo nesseccary for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `searchForFriendsQuery` looks fine to me at first glance. But that's not what you're passing to the adapter, as you're still using `allUsersDatabaseRef` there:

```
 .setQuery(allUsersDatabaseRef, FindFriends.class)
```

That should probably be:

```
 .setQuery(searchForFriendsQuery, FindFriends.class)
```

Comment: Thank you So much for your kindly Help :))) It is working now but still not really proparly...It doesnt show all the users..for example if I search for m/M it doesn't show any users but i Have 2 users in my database with m/M names :( can you please help me with that also?

Comment: That's hard to say from what you shared, but keep in mind that Firebase will only search for users that **start with** M. It doesn't support searching for nodes that **contain** M.